# Sorting in javascript using functions or using underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, underscore.js

I need to sort an array such that each object is sorted alphabetically by name.  I need to achieve this using native functions or with the underscore library.

This is my JSON data:

```
var data = [
    {
        name: "xyz",
        size: "small"
    },
    {
        name: "abc",
        size: "large"
    },
        {
        name: "fcd",
        size: "large"
    },
];
```

This is my sample json file. I want the object with name abc to appear first in the array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var data; // This is your data array

data.sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
   }
   if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
   }
   // a must equal b
   return 0;
});
```

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Every time that name abc doesn't comes  as second element..there are may be extra names too..In that case this doesn't work right?

Comment: This code will still work if the array is in a different order or if the array has more objects. As long as each object has a `name` property to sort by, it will work!

Answer (score -1):

Open your console and run this code to see it sort your objects.

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "xyz",
    size: "small"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    size: "large"
  },
  {
    name: "fcd",
    size: "large"
  },
];
    
console.log(
data.sort(function(obj1, obj2){ return obj1.name > obj2.name})
);
```

Comment: The comparison function for [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is supposed to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Every time that name abc doesn't comes  as second element..there are may be extra names too..In that case this doesn't work right?

Comment: I've scrambled them in all sorts of ways and it keeps coming out correct (including adding and removing elements).  `Number(true)` and `Number(false)` cast to `1` and `0`.  Probably the sorting algorithm will take a few more iterations without `-1` as on option.  But it works fine.